# Triangle inequality $\frac{ab}{a^{2}+ b^{2}}+ \frac{bc}{b^{2}+ c^{2}}+ \frac{ca}{c^{2}+ a^{2}}\geq \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{2r}{R}$

Tags: geometry, inequality, fractions, geometric-inequalities, sum-of-squares-method

Suppose that $a, b, c$ be the lengths of 3 sides of a triangle, $r$ is the inradius of the circle and $R$ is the circumradius of the circle. Prove that
$$\frac{ab}{a^{2}+ b^{2}}+ \frac{bc}{b^{2}+ c^{2}}+ \frac{ca}{c^{2}+ a^{2}}\geq  \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{2r}{R}$$
It' s so amazing, I tried to use Euler and Gerretsen's inequality.

###### Source

[The following AoPS post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1610453p10054627) qualifies as a source. Please see the discussion following the question.

###### Results which can be used

> Euler's inequality : $R \geq 2r$, where $R,r$ are the circumradius and inradius respectively.

> Gerritsen's inequality : Let $R,r$ be as above and $s$ be the semiperimeter of the triangle. Then, $$
> 16Rr - 5r^2 \leq s^2 \leq 4R^2+4Rr+3r^2
> $$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843214/proving-gerretsens-inequality) for a proof of Gerritsen's inequality.

Comment: Have you told us what $r$ and $R$ mean?

Comment: Yes, I know. $2R= \frac{a}{\sin A}= \frac{b}{\sin B}= \frac{c}{\sin C}$ and $r= \frac{abc}{2R\left ( a+ b+ c \right )}$

Comment: $R,r$ circum- and in-radii of a triangle.

Comment: I've reopened this question after the significant edit has improved the post considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard notation we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}\geq\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\frac{4S}{a+b+c}}{\frac{abc}{4S}}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq\frac{16S^2}{abc(a+b+c)}-1$$ or
$$1-\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)}{abc}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{2(a^2+b^2)}$$ or
$$\frac{2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)}{abc}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{a^2+b^2}$$ or
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^3-2abc-2(a^2c+b^2c-2abc))}{abc}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{a^2+b^2}$$ or
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b-c)}{abc}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{a^2+b^2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(a+b-c-\frac{abc}{a^2+b^2}\right)\geq0.$$
Now, let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, by AM-GM $$a+b-c-\frac{abc}{a^2+b^2}\geq a+b-c-\frac{abc}{2ab}=a+b-1.5c>0$$ and
$$a+c-b-\frac{abc}{a^2+c^2}\geq c-\frac{abc}{a^2+c^2}=c\left(1-\frac{ab}{a^2+c^2}\right)>0.$$
Id est, since $c>a-b$, we obtain: $$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left(a+b-c-\frac{abc}{a^2+b^2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(a-c)^2\left(a+c-b-\frac{abc}{a^2+c^2}\right)+(b-c)^2\left(b+c-a-\frac{abc}{b^2+c^2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq(b-c)^2\left(a+c-b-\frac{abc}{a^2+c^2}\right)+(b-c)^2\left(b+c-a-\frac{abc}{b^2+c^2}\right)=$$
$$=c(b-c)^2\left(2-ab\left(\frac{1}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}\right)\right)>$$
$$>c(b-c)^2\left(2-ab\left(\frac{1}{a^2+(a-b)^2}+\frac{1}{b^2+(a-b)^2}\right)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{c(b-c)^2(a-b)^2(4a^2-7ab+4b^2)}{(a^2+(a-b)^2)(b^2+(a-b)^2)}\geq0.$$

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a weaker inequality
$$\frac{c^{2}}{a^{2}+ b^{2}}+ \frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}+ c^{2}}+ \frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}+ a^{2}}\leq  \frac{2R- r}{2R}$$
Proof
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}+ c^{2}}+ \frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}+ a^{2}}+ \frac{c^{2}}{a^{2}+ b^{2}}\leq  \frac{a^{3}+ b^{3}+ c^{3}}{2abc}\\
a^{3}+ b^{3}+ c^{3}= 2s^{3}- 12R- 6r\\
abc= 4R\\
\Leftrightarrow LHS\leq  \frac{s^{2}- 6Rr- 3r^{2}}{4Rr}\leq_{GERRETSEN}  \frac{\left ( 4R^{2}+ 4Rr+ 3r^{2} \right )- 6Rr- 3r^{2}}{4Rr}= \frac{2R- r}{2r}\\
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}+ c^{2}}+ \frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}+ a^{2}}+ \frac{c^{2}}{a^{2}+ b^{2}}\geq  \frac{\left ( b- c \right )^{2}}{b^{2}+ c^{2}}+ \frac{\left ( c- a \right )^{2}}{c^{2}+ a^{2}}+ \frac{\left ( a- b \right )^{2}}{a^{2}+ b^{2}}\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{bc}{b^{2}+ c^{2}}+ \frac{ca}{c^{2}+ a^{2}}+ \frac{ab}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\geq  \frac{7r- 2R}{4r}\ngeqslant \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{2r}{R}
\end{align*}$$
I can't succeed in proving this inequality by use it! How about another solution? I want to see more.

Comment: What is a relation between the starting inequality and your work?

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{c^{2}}{a^{2}+ b^{2}}+ \frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}+ c^{2}}+ \frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}+ a^{2}}\leq  \frac{2R- r}{2R}$$
Proof
                        [image]

[image]

Comment: @Đăng Đặng Hải What is a relation between the starting inequality and your work?