# For $a$, $b$, $c$ the sides of a triangle, show $ 7(a+b+c)^3-9(a+b+c)\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)-108abc\ge0$

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangle-inequality

> If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the three sidelengths of an arbitrary triangle, prove that the following inequality is true, with equality for equilateral triangles.
>
> $$ 7\left(a+b+c\right)^3-9\left(a+b+c\right)\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)-108abc\ge0 \tag{1}$$

In expanded form:
$$ 6\left(a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b \right)-\left(a^3+b^3+c^3\right)-33abc\ge0 \tag{2}$$

This a part of an ongoing research in triangle geometry and related to solving a cubic equation.

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: This is a part of an ongoing research in triangle geometry and related to solving a cubic equation. If you can, prove that the inequality is wrong.

Comment: Why do you type $\pmb a$, $\pmb b$, and $\pmb c$ in the first line of the question, but then you simply type $a$, $b$, and $c$ after that?

Comment: Could the "triangular notation" (http://www.aquatutoring.org/TriangularNotation.pdf) be used here ?

Comment: Hint: express the terms using R and r.

Comment: I have tried to use Schur's inequality and some other similar inequalities in vain.

Comment: No.In triangle geometry inequality you don’t use Schur, you use R and r to replace those a,b,c expressions. Read the book geometric inequalities by Mitrinovic and Pecaric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}\geq\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdots a_n}$$
Since $a,~ b,~ c$ are positive real numbers
$$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3}=abc$$
$$a^3+b^3+c^3\geq3abc$$
$$2(a^3+b^3+c^3)\geq6abc\tag{1}$$
Now we want to prove that
$$2a^2(b + c) + 2b^2(c + a) + 2c^2(a + b) ≥ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 9abc\tag{2}$$
First let
$$ \begin{cases} 
        a = y + z  \\
       b = z + x \\
       c = x + y
   \end{cases}
$$
With $x,~y,~z\geq0$, then the left side of $(2)$ becomes
$$4x^3 + 4y^3 + 4z^3 + 10x^2(y + z) + 10y^2(z + x) + 10z^2(x + y) + 24xyz$$
And the right side becomes
$$2x^3 + 2y^3 + 2z^3 + 12x^2(y + z) + 12y^2(z + x) + 12z^2(x + y) + 18xyz$$
Further simplify we have
$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 3xyz ≥ x^2(y + z) + y^2(z +x) + z^2(x + y)$$
which is [Schur's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality), so we have proved that $(2)$ holds true.

From $(2)$ we have
$$6(a^2(b + c) + b^2(c + a) + c^2(a + b)) ≥ 3(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 27abc\tag{3}$$
Add $(1)$ and $(3)$
$$6\left(a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b \right)+2(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge 3(a^3+b^3+c^3)+33abc$$
$$ 6\left(a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b \right)-\left(a^3+b^3+c^3\right)-33abc\ge0 $$
and we're done.

Comment: You can't subtract two inequalities directly like that!!!

Comment: Ok, I have made the corrections.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align} 
7\left(a+b+c\right)^3-9\left(a+b+c\right)\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)-108abc
&\ge0
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

As @DeepSea suggested, we can replace 
the expressions in terms of side lengths $a,b,c$ 
with equivalent in terms of semiperimeter $\rho=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$,
inradius $r$ and 
circumradius $R$ of the triangle, knowing that

\begin{align}
a+b+c&=2\rho
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
a^2+b^2+c^2&=2(\rho^2-r^2-4rR)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
abc&=4\rho\,r\,R
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}
so \eqref{1} is becomes

\begin{align}
7(2\rho)^3-9(2\rho)\cdot2(\rho^2-r^2-4rR)-108\cdot4\rho\,r\,R
&\ge0
,\\
20\rho^3+36\rho\,r^2-288\rho\,r\,R
&\ge0
,\\
5\rho^2+9 r^2-72 rR
&\ge0
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\end{align}

And ve can divide \eqref{5} by $R^2$
and consider new $\rho,r$ that correspond
to a scaled triangle with $R=1$:

\begin{align}
5\rho^2+9 r^2-72 r
&\ge0
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Using 
the left part of 
[Gerretsen's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843214/proving-gerretsens-inequality),

\begin{align}
r\,(16\,R-5\,r)&\le\rho^2
,
\end{align}

we can check if/when 
\begin{align}
5\,r\,(16-5\,r)+9 r^2-72 r
&\ge0
\end{align}
instead of \eqref{6}, which simplifies to 
\begin{align}
1-2\,r
&\ge0
,
\end{align}

which holds for $r\in[0,\tfrac12]$,
that is, for all valid triangles.

Hence, \eqref{1}.

Answer (score 1):

By your work $$7(a+b+c)^3-9(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)-108abc=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(12a^2b+12a^2c-2a^3-22abc)=\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-2a^3+11(a^2b+a^2c-2abc))=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}a^2(c-a-(a-b))+11(b^2c+a^2c-2abc))=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}((a-b)(b^2-a^2)+11c(a-b)^2))=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(11c-a-b)\geq\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(3c-a-b).$$
Now, let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, since $3a-b-c>0$, $3b-a-c\geq b+c-a>0$ and $a-c\geq a-b$, we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(3c-a-b)\geq(a-b)^2(3c-a-b)+(a-c)^2(3b-a-c)\geq$$
$$\geq(a-b)^2(3c-a-b)+(a-b)^2(3b-a-c)=2(a-b)^2(b+c-a)\geq0.$$