# Prove that $21(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge 20 +9(a^3+b^3+c^3)$

Tags: inequality, summation, triangles, geometric-inequalities, tangent-line-method

Let $a,b,c$ be the length of sides of triangle such that $a+b+c=2$. Prove that
$$21(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge 20 +9(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$

---

It was in my exam. It can be solved easy by BW but it takes alot of time to expand. I tried to use Schur, AM-GM but all failed.Help me solve it without bw.

Comment: What is this BW     ?

Comment: Please put at least one of your attempts in the question.

Comment: @JCAA See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h522084 It indeed helps here.

Comment: @JCAA:  see also [this](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/the-buffalo-way/)

Answer (score 5):

Let $a=\frac{2}{3}x$, $b=\frac{2}{3}y$ and $c=\frac{2}{3}z$.

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are also sides-lengths of a triangle, $x+y+z=3$ and we need to prove that:
$$7(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq15+2(x^3+y^3+z^3)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^3-7x^2+5)\leq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-1)(2x^2-5x-5)\leq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}((x-1)(2x^2-5x-5)+8(x-1))\leq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-1)^2(3-2x)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-1)^2(y+z-x)\geq0$$ and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality equivalent to
$$21(a^2+b^2+c^2) \cdot \frac{a+b+c}{2}\ge \frac52(a+b+c)^3 +9(a^3+b^3+c^3).$$
Using Ravi substitution for $a = x+y,\,b=y+z,\,c=z+x$ with $x,\,y,\,z > 0$ inequality become
$$4(x^3+y^3+z^3)+6xyz \geqslant 3[xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(z+x)]. \quad (1)$$
From Schur inequality
$$x^3+y^3+z^3 +3xyz \geqslant xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(z+x),$$
we need to prove
$$2(x^3+y^3+z^3) \geqslant xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(z+x).$$
Which is true because $x^3+y^3 \geqslant xy(x+y).$

**Note.** The sum of squares of $(1)$
$$x(y+z-2x)^2+y(z+x-2y)^2+z(x+y-2z)^2 \geqslant 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

We write inequality as
$$21(a^2+b^2+c^2) \cdot \frac{a+b+c}{2} \geqslant \frac52(a+b+c)^3 +9(a^3+b^3+c^3),$$
or
$$42s(s^2-4Rr-r^2) \geqslant 20s^3+18s(s^2-6Rr-3r^2),$$
or
$$4s(s^2+3r^2-15Rr) \geqslant 0.$$
But
$$s^2+3r^2-15Rr = r(R-2r)+(s^2-16Rr+5r^2) \geqslant 0.$$
Which is true by [Euler's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry) inequality and [Gerretsen's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843214/proving-gerretsens-inequality) inequality.